# Google Maps iOS SDK crash

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I use google maps iOS SDK with storyboard. Application starting with Navigation View Controller that has a Root View Controller with map.

```
@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize btnMyLock;
@synthesize btnNearby;

GMSMapView *mapView_;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:20
                                                        longitude:20
                                                             zoom:0];

     mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
     mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;

     self.view = mapView_;
     // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
     GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
     [marker setIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin"]];
     marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
     marker.title = @"Sydney";
     marker.snippet = @"Australia";
     marker.map = mapView_;

     mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;

     [mapView_ addSubview:btnMyLock];
     [mapView_ addSubview:btnNearby]; 
}
```

Button btnMyLock push the Table View Controller. In iOS 7 it's ok. But iOS 6 my app crashes. Sometimes crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1) or code=2

Comment: I'm making nothing and the app was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem that I used Autolayout view.

Comment: I am not using auto layout. still my app randomly crashes in map screen. Need help. Somebody please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot step 4: "**Drag the GoogleMaps.bundle**" from the Resources folder to your project.

I suggest putting it in the Frameworks group. When prompted, ensure "Copy items into destination group’s folder" is not selected. i encountered the same problem, and this fixed it.

Comment: GoogleMaps.bundle exists in project. I added that without "copy". On iOS 7 app work and on iOS 6 crash.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's causing the problem, but I wouldn't do:

```
self.view = mapView_;
```

Just add the `mapView_` as a subview, like:

```
[self.view addSubview:mapView_];
```

---

In general EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes are caused when you are mismanaging memory (e.g. an object is being deallocated prematurely). Try to find out what object the crash is happening on.

---

Create your buttons in code, not from the xib as IBOutlets. Otherwise they are not loaded since you are not using the xib.

Comment: It's from google maps SDK tutorial

[google maps sdk](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start)

When I commented self.view = mapView_; -- it's work.

Comment: And if you add the view as subview like the code I posted? Still the crash? And how are your buttons created?

Comment: @RolandKeeson I fix the bug. Buttons are outlets. I make nothing, that's all. Magic.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code when you use Google map and then check its not crash when you navigate to another screen.

```
- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
[mapView_ removeObserver:self
              forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
                 context:NULL];
}
```